# Is there a good way to store a boolean array into a file or database in python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am building an image mosaic that detect if the user's selected area are taken or not.
My idea is to store the available_spots in a list, and I would just have to look through the list to check whether a spot is available or not.

The problem is that when I reload the website, avaliable_spots also gets reset to blank list,
so I want to store this array somewhere, that is fast to read and write to.

I am currently thinking about a text file to store this, but that might take forever to read since array length is over 1.4 million. Is there any other solutions that might be better?

Answer (score 0):

You can't store the data in a file for a few reasons: (1) GAE standard won't let you, (2) the data is lost when your server is restarted, and (3) different instances will have different data.

Of course you can and should store the data in a database of your choice.  Firestore is likely a better and cheaper option than SQL.  It should be fast enough for you and you can implement caching if needed.

You might be able to store the data in a single Firestore entity and consider using compression if you are getting close to the max entity size.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to store into a database you can use the "sqlite3" module.
Is a simple database that gets stored in a file so you dont have to install a database program. Is great for small projects.

If you want to do more complex stuff with databases you can use "sqlalchemy".